# How to find the Laplace transform to find the solution to a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, inverse, laplace-transform

I am having some trouble understanding the proper way to take the inverse Laplace transform to obtain a solution. I am following a paper found here [[1]](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0020739031000071467/463-470), which provides the solution to the following PDE,
$$
\frac{\partial m}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial m}{\partial a} = -\lambda(a,t)m\\
m(t,0) = B(t)\\
m(0,a) = m_{0}(a)
$$
If I take the laplace transform with respect to $t$, using $p$ as the transform variable, I obtain,
$$
\frac{\partial \hat{m}}{\partial a} + p\hat{m}-m_{0}(a) = -\lambda(a)\hat{m}
$$
I can use integrating factor $e^{\int^{a}_{0}p+\lambda(\alpha)d\alpha}$ to obtain an expression for $\hat{m}$ as,
$$
\hat{m}(p,a) = e^{-pa}e^{-\int^{a}_{0}\lambda(\alpha)d\alpha}\int^{a}_{0}m_{0}(\xi)e^{p\xi}e^{\int^{\xi}_{0}\lambda(\alpha)d\alpha}d\xi+\hat{B}(p)e^{-\int^{a}_{0}\lambda(\alpha)d\alpha}
$$

In the linked paper, the authors obtain the solution as,
$$
m(t,a) = B(t-a)\sigma(a)H(t-a) + m_{0}(a-t)\sigma(t)H(a-t)
$$

Where $\sigma(a) = e^{-\int^{a}_{0}\lambda(\alpha)d\alpha}$

Whilst I understand the general formula for inverse laplace transform in this context would be,
$$
L^{-1}\{e^{-cs}F(s)\} = f(t-c)H(t-c)
$$
Where H is the heaviside function. I do not understand how to apply it in this context. Would someone be able to help me out?

Comment: Why do you want to use that expressions for the shifted Laplace transform, the cited paper works through this Laplace inversions step by step? At what point do you not follow the derivation? Besides, there are two typos in your question: 1) the author considers the case $\lambda(a,t)=\lambda(a)$ and 2) there is a factor $e^{-pa}$ missing in your $\hat{m}(p,a)$ expressions.